# How to run Jenkins stanadlone pipeline daily-overnight if jenkins file is using plan ={} section

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on Jenkinsfile based test pipeline.
We have a standalone test automation job that needs to be run daily overnight.

The structure itself is something like below:

```
MyPipeline {
artefactType = "dockerTool"
shouldNotifySlackOnAnyBuildStatus = true
isDockerBuild = true
slackChannelName = "****-api-test-notifications-channel"
plan = {
    stage('Build tests') {
        sh "docker build --network=host --build-arg CACHE_BUST=\$(date +%s) -t ${DOCKER_IMAGE} ."
    }
    stage('Run tests') {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '**-api-test-framework-client-secret', variable: 'CLIENT_SECRET'),
                          string(credentialsId: '**-api-test-framework-client-id', variable: 'CLIENT_ID')]) {
            script {
                  sh 'docker run --network=host --name $DOCKER_IMAGE -e "clientSecret=$CLIENT_SECRET" -e "clientID=$CLIENT_ID" -e "suiteFile=testng.xml" -e "testplan=testng.xml" -e "env=qa" $DOCKER_IMAGE'
              }
          }
      }
}
finallyCallback = {
    stage('Publish Report') { ............
```

How & where to introduce overnight build descriptor, so that this job would get triggered daily at mid-night.

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't look like a Jenkinsfile syntax, could you elaborate on this? My only assumption is that you define `<OurpipelineName>Pipeline` in `vars` of a shared library, but I didn't think Jenkins allows to inject the stages like this.

Comment: I have removed/hide project specific name & put a generic plaeholder

Comment: Still... It doesn't help a lot, unfortunately. Could you confirm my assumption? If yes, then most likely I have an answer. If not, it would be helpful to know more about your pipeline implementation to suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To schedule your Jenkins standalone pipeline to run daily overnight, you can use the Jenkins built-in feature called "[Build Triggers](https://blog.knoldus.com/jenkins-build-triggers/)". Specifically, you will use the "[Build periodically](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/how-to-schedule-a-jenkins-job#how-to-schedule-a-jenkins-job)" option, which allows you to define schedules using `cron` syntax.

Since you are using a job DSL or Jenkins Configuration as Code, you would define the trigger in a separate job definition.

```
job('your-job-name') {
    // Other job configurations like parameters, SCM settings, etc.

    // Add the scheduled trigger
    triggers {
        cron('H 0 * * *') // That schedules the job to run daily at midnight
    }

    // Define your pipeline steps or script
    steps {
        // Your existing steps, like running a shell script or a Jenkins pipeline
        // For example, if you are invoking a Jenkinsfile:
        pipelineScript {
            // Reference to your Jenkinsfile, e.g. from SCM
            // scriptPath('path/to/your/Jenkinsfile')
        }
    }

    // Additional job settings like publishers, build wrappers, etc.
}
```

That tells Jenkins to run the job at midnight every day. The `H` symbol spreads out the load on the system by randomizing the execution time around the specified hour.

`path/to/your/Jenkinsfile` would reference your current Jenkinsfile which cannot directly schedule itself, since it is probably using a [shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).

---

> What should be the name of this file?
> Also, how will this file be triggered in the first place? Will it just be based on filename?

The file containing the Job DSL script does not have a required name; you can name it anything that makes sense for your project, such as `jenkinsJobDefinition.groovy` or simply `jobDSL.groovy`. The key is not the file name, but how and where you run this DSL script to create or update Jenkins jobs.

You can trigger this DSL script to define or update your Jenkins jobs by first making sure your Jenkins instance has the [Job DSL plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl/) installed. That plugin is what processes the DSL scripts to create or update jobs in Jenkins.
You can then create a "seed" job in Jenkins, which is a freestyle or Pipeline job designed specifically to run Job DSL scripts.
In a **Pipeline job**, you can use the `dsl` step to execute the Job DSL script. The script can be loaded from SCM or directly included in the Pipeline script.

The seed job is triggered like any other Jenkins job. You can trigger it manually, on a schedule (using "Build periodically"), or via a webhook from your source control system. When triggered, the seed job reads and executes the Job DSL script, which in turn creates or updates the jobs as defined in the script.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Run Job DSL Script') {
            steps {
                checkout scm // Checks out the source code from SCM
                script {
                    // Assuming 'jobDSL.groovy' is the DSL script in your SCM
                    def dslScript = readFile 'path/to/jobDSL.groovy'
                    dsl {
                        text dslScript
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What should be the name of this file? Also, how this file will be triggered in first place? will it just based on filename?

Comment: @VonC I don't see any signs that the OP uses JobDSL though. The [triggers](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers) directive does not require usage of JobDSL either. Also, according to the JobDSL plugin [API reference](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/job), one can define the steps via JobDSL for a freestyle job only, that in fact doesn't have a Jenkinsfile - did it work for you? For pipeline and multibranch pipeline there's no API to define the steps, the Jenkinsfile path has to be set up in different places, and for pipeline `triggers` are deprecated.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev I agree. My test case was too simple.

Answer (score 2):

Your Jenkinsfile looks like it's using a shared library, where the whole pipeline is defined as a Groovy script in `vars` folder  (reference: [Defining Declarative Pipelines](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-declarative-pipelines)).

So, the exact place where the build schedule could be defined depends on your custom implementation.

That Groovy file most likely looks something like this:

```java
// vars/MyPipeline.groovy

def call(body) {
   def pipelineParameters
   pipelineParameters = [:]
   body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
   body.delegate = pipelineParameters
   body()

   pipeline {
       agent {
           // ...
       }
       stages {
           // ...
       }
       // ...
   }
}
```

In this example, `pipelineParameters` represent the parameters defined in your Jenkinsfile, such as `plan`, `isDockerBuild`, and others.

So, if that's the case, you can add a [`triggers`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers) block to it:

```java
// vars/MyPipeline.groovy

def call(body) {
   def pipelineParameters
   pipelineParameters = [:]
   body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
   body.delegate = pipelineParameters
   body()

   pipeline {
       agent {
           // ...
       }
       triggers {
           cron('H H(0-4) * * 1-5')
       }
       stages {
           // ...
       }
       // ...
   }
}
```

Of course you can parametrize it:

```java
// vars/MyPipeline.groovy

def call(body) {
   def pipelineParameters
   pipelineParameters = [:]
   body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
   body.delegate = pipelineParameters
   body()

   pipeline {
       agent {
           // ...
       }
       triggers {
           cron(pipelineParameters.cron)
       }
       stages {
           // ...
       }
       // ...
   }
}
```

```java
// Jenkinsfile

MyPipeline {
    cron = 'H H(0-4) * * 1-5'
    artefactType = "dockerTool"
    shouldNotifySlackOnAnyBuildStatus = true
    isDockerBuild = true
    slackChannelName = "****-api-test- 
    notifications-channel"
    plan = {
        stage('Build tests') {
            sh "docker build --network=host --build-arg CACHE_BUST=\$(date +%s) -t ${DOCKER_IMAGE} ."
        }
        stage('Run tests') {   
      
      withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '**-api-test-framework-client-secret', variable: 'CLIENT_SECRET'),
                          string(credentialsId: '**-api-test-framework-client-id', variable: 'CLIENT_ID')]) {
            script {
                  sh 'docker run --network=host --name $DOCKER_IMAGE -e "clientSecret=$CLIENT_SECRET" -e "clientID=$CLIENT_ID" -e "suiteFile=testng.xml" -e "testplan=testng.xml" -e "env=qa" $DOCKER_IMAGE'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finallyCallback = {
        stage('Publish Report') {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Moreover, even more customization should be possible using Groovy - for example, you can set the schedule only for `master` branch, which is useful with multibranch pipelines:

```java
MyPipeline {
    cron = env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master' ? 'H H(0-4) * * 1-5' : ''
    // ...
}
```

Now, to an alternative solution.

It looks like you've managed to inject the whole stages to that pipeline. So chances are that you can define the `triggers` block in your Jenkinsfile, too, and inject it the same way as the stages. But without knowing the implementation details it's impossible to make a more precise suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way to fix this would be to add a variable that stores time, and will trigger every x amount of time based on the time of day it is. If you want it to trigger at midnight, you can add a tracker that will go up every second of the script running, and start running it at midnight. If you leave it running all day, in theory, when the counter hits 86400, then add a function that resets the counter to zero, then run the script. I hope this helps @user2451016!

Comment: How is it related to Jenkins? And why do that if Jenkins has built-in cron scheduler for pipelines?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with Jenkins, but if you cannot get it working, I was just suggesting that you could do a similar function using Jenkins, just to send you in the right direction. Not really instructions, but more of just a nudge in the right direction. Sorry for the misunderstanding.